# Is there a way to experience peppers’s endorphins effects without the burning sensation?

Tags: food-chemistry, taste

When preparing dinner, my friend and I sometimes argue over the amount of pepper. It is often ‘too hot’ for him while I enjoy the heat effects (endorphins) of capsaicin (chili peppers) and piperine (black pepper). Is there a way to experience the endorphins effects of pepper without a burning sensation?

Comment: You might find more experienced people over at [cooking.se]

Comment: Anecdotally, many people claim that you can use an acidic solution like lemon juice and/or vinegar to make it seem less spicy (even tomatoes). This is one of the reasons vinegar is used for hot sauce. You can dilute hot sauce with vinegar to make it less hot but diluting with water doesn't work well. The same with chili. People use tomato sauce rather than water to dilute chili that is too hot.